# django.contrib.message Translation

Tags: python, django, localization

Need to translate the django contrib messages into diffrent languages.

Here is the code i tried:

In Views.py

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

messages.success(self.request, _("Sample text"))
```

In template:

```html
{% for message in messages %}
   <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
      {{ message }}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But the text is not getting translated. Is there any particular way to translate this? I am using python3 and django 1.11

Comment: This is from doc, *"“Text should be translated into the end user’s language, if a translation for this text is available in that language.”"* Where you are testing?

Comment: Did you run `makemessages`, edited the `.po` files, and run `compilemessages`? Please be more specific.

Comment: translation text is placed in the PO file and compiled. Still it not giving the translation only for this message

Comment: Test with `get_language_info()`, you will get name of the language in english and in your language. If they both are in english, you won't see any change.

Comment: @Shijo Try `{% trans message %}`

Answer (score 4):

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('fr', 'French')
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True
```

then :

`python manage.py makemessages -l fr`

translate messages in locale folder for french language

and then `python manage.py compilemessages -l fr`